# Start docker error on Antergos (Arch Linux)

Tags: docker, archlinux, antergos

I have installed docker on Antergos (Arch Linux) and followed this guide: https://gist.github.com/simonhoye/3b7312c05a449cd9073f9dc9265f5213

But when I execute `sudo sysytemctl start docker` I get this error:

`Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

And this is the `systemctl status docker.service` command:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor pres>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-01-17 16:28:01 CET; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 17013 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAI>
 Main PID: 17013 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expir>
ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart>
ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too qui>
ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 17 16:28:01 t480 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container E>`
```

I have not idea what is happening... Because the guide and the steps to follow are very simple.

Answer (score 0):

it can be due to many reason so I am listing some common one's

- look inside **/var/log/syslog** for more info.
- If you remove **/var/lib/docker**, you'll **lose existing images** but it works for many people

  - Doing so simply wipes all your docker data, and is the equivalent to a "factory reset".
- it can also be due to missing kernel module **aufs**
- deleting the **/var/run/docker.sock** directory that had been created presumably as the **docker service was shutting down**